# How to use Bearer or Apikey keywords automatically onswagger java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to make some security configurations in my `SwaggerConfiguration` class. My purpose is sending scheme keyword with authentication key like

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Bearer <authorization-value>"
```

or

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: ApiKey <authorization-value>"
```

It is possible on [ASP.NET Core](https://codeburst.io/api-security-in-swagger-f2afff82fb8e) but I can only achieve this in Java like this:

[image]

What shall I use for my Docket security scheme instead of `ApiKey`?

```
Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("mypackagename"))
                    .build()
                    .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                    .apiInfo(metaData())
                    .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(getApiKey()))
                    .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));

private ApiKey getApiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("apiKey", "Authorization", "Header");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by Open API Specification 3. To do that  you need to add a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${open.api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

After including this you need to update the swagger configuration as and post that you do not need add Bearer scheme in front of your token:

```
package com.test.config;
    
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    @Log4j2
    public class SwaggerConfig {
        private static final String SCHEME_NAME = "bearerScheme";
        private static final String SCHEME = "Bearer";
        
        @Bean
        public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
            var openApi = new OpenAPI()
                    .info(getInfo());
    
            addSecurity(openApi);
    
            return openApi;
        }

        private Info getInfo() {
            return new Info()
                    .title("Your APIs Documentation")
                    .description("The API documentation for your Portal.")
                    .version("1.0.0")
                    .license(getLicense());
        }
    
        private License getLicense() {
            return new License()
                    .name("Your")
                    .url("https://www.yours.com/en/");
        }
        private void addSecurity(OpenAPI openApi) {
            var components = createComponents();
            var securityItem = new SecurityRequirement().addList(SCHEME_NAME);
    
            openApi
                    .components(components)
                    .addSecurityItem(securityItem);
        }
    
        private Components createComponents() {
            var components = new Components();
            components.addSecuritySchemes(SCHEME_NAME, createSecurityScheme());
    
            return components;
        }
    
        private SecurityScheme createSecurityScheme() {
            return new SecurityScheme()
                    .name(SCHEME_NAME)
                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                    .scheme(SCHEME);
        }
    
    }
```

For details you can refer [this](https://keepgrowing.in/java/springboot/how-to-secure-spring-boot-swagger-ui-with-basic-authentication/).

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot

Comment: @W33R What if I want to use 'ApkiKey' keyword instead of 'Bearer'

Comment: @EminBilgiç it should work.